# Microsoft Graph API DeltaLinks for Shared Mailboxes Never Return Changes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a Office 365 Business Essentials Exchange Online Shared Mailbox I need to retrieve changes for on a scheduled basis.  Access to this mailbox is granted to an AzureAD registered app via the Microsoft Graph API `Mail.ReadWrite` application permission.  Admin consent has been acquired.  Mailbox access is limited to just this one mailbox through an [ApplicationAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access).

As this is a simple test case on a brand new mailbox that only contains a handful of test emails, I didn't use any filters or search terms.  The initial request is in the format: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{ID}/mailFolders/{ID}/messages/delta?$select=sender,receivedDateTime,subject,body`

I have no issues retrieving an access_token.  The initial request and subsequent `nextLink` requests return results without issue as well.  However, making a request against the `deltaLink` always returns an empty dataset.  This occurs regardless of any changes made to messages in the folder since the `deltaLink` was retrieved. Instead I get the following response:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(message)",
    "@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/mailFolders/{id}/messages/delta?$deltatoken=GoHFWffpmGHQHQdBstC3TW7TDQ4HvoU5hdqPXQ_DvM724L0CdVdFzRNBLVaICnIxrI9zMjxaHP7k0ncrSZj9L48EjNP7Hveu8IgKvkNUCGoRun6G89JzwGgNqn93Z4L5vtS8Fup2E6W6VD4LKMWehk5I6xWxPJMy8WwKsSrm8AJA0phlbIrqciV6G3MiQ67Q.xJrwL7OVVHnlcdTlcdctrLBRzRHLUZnpFCxbZL7MrCg",
    "value": []
}
```

This behavior occurs whether I run the query from the registered application or via my own account using the Microsoft Graph Explorer.

Am I missing a step somewhere along the way or is this a bug?  If the latter does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: This may be a bug, unlikely that this is something you control. Does the deltaLink change each time you make a call to it? Are you seeing this same behavior if you use this against an individual's mailbox?

Comment: @MichaelMainer, the deltaLink only changes if I perform a fresh query.  The deltaLink does not change when I call a preexisting deltaLink.  
As regards to your second question, after doing a few tests I can say that I'm experiencing this issue for individual mailboxes as well.

Comment: Are you still experiencing the same issue? Could you provide a request id please?